# Jquery show on hover hide on click

Tags: jquery, hover, show-hide

I have an element I am trying to have show on hover and stay shown. Then hides when anywhere is clicked or the button previously hovered is clicked. I have code that works, BUT it switches the hover effect if the button is clicked.

Button hover = div shown

div shown and anywhere outside clicked = div hidden

**div shown and button clicked = div hides on hover and shows after mouse moves off button**

I'd like to have the div hide when the button is clicked and stay hidden after the mouse is no longer hovering. NOT reappear after the mouse moves off the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.email-div').hide();
                $('.showemail').hover(function() {
                    var takeClass = $(this).attr('class');
                        $('.email-div').show();
                });
        });
        $(document).on("click", function () {
                $(".email-div").hide();
        });
</script>

<a class="showemail">
    Button
</a>

<div class="email-div">
   <p>Subscribe your email</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:-

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.email-div').hide();
     $('.showemail').hover(function() {
              if(!$(this).hasClass('hoverd'))
              {
                  $(this).addClass('hoverd')
                    $('.email-div').show();
              }
     },function(){
     $(this).removeClass('hoverd')
     });
 });
 $(document).on("click", function () {
   $(".email-div").hide();
  });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a3aq0qqt/)

Answer (score 2):

Try using mouseenter instead of hover

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/toLt4tfg/1/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.email-div').hide();
            $('.showemail').mouseenter(function() {

                    $('.email-div').show();
            });
    });
    $(document).on("click", function () {
            $(".email-div").hide();
    });
```

Comment: This works but when you click into the div it disappears. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add a click event handler to the email-div for stopping event propagation - https://jsfiddle.net/toLt4tfg/2/